# Segmentation Fault when detecting file extension

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I can't know where is the problem in my program, i used a debuger but it doesn't specify in which line is the error

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE //pour nofile

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <magic.h>



int main (void)
{
    const char *description;
    magic_t cookie;

    FILE* Texte= NULL;
    if(NULL == (Texte = fopen("chaines", "r")) )
    { // then fopen failed
    perror( "fopen failed for chaines for read");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful
    cookie = magic_open(MAGIC_NONE);
    description = magic_descriptor(cookie, fileno(Texte));
    printf("%s\n", description);
return 0;
}

And this is my debuger result
    Starting program: /home/hamza/Bureau/Projet_suffixe/suffixe_db 
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7888e41 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Thank you.

Comment: Recompile with debug symbols.

Comment: Could it be that `magic_open` returns `NULL` on failure?

Comment: Check that magic_open() succeds. If so, check that magic_descriptor() succeeds.

Comment: sorry i'm a begginer , how to compile with debug symbols ?

Comment: You'd add the -g flag when compiling. gcc g -o yourprogram yourprogram.c -lmagic

Comment: this is what i made  gcc -g Suffixe.c -lmagic -o suffixe_db

Comment: How can I compile without writing -l magic ? Where should I move the magic.h file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that `magic_open` and `magic_descriptor` succeeded, and load the magic database by means of the `magic_load()` function.

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE //pour nofile

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <magic.h>

int main (void)
{
    magic_t cookie;

    FILE* Texte= NULL;
    if (NULL == (Texte = fopen("chaines", "r")) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for chaines for read");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful
    cookie = magic_open(MAGIC_NONE);
    if (cookie != NULL)
    {
        /* you should load the database */
        if (magic_load(cookie, NULL) == 0)
        {
            const char *description;

            description = magic_descriptor(cookie, fileno(Texte));
            if (description != NULL)
                printf("%s\n", description);
            else
                printf("Unknown\n");
            magic_close(cookie); // cleanup resources
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "error loading the magic database\n");
    }
    fclose(Texte); // cleanup resources

    return 0;
}
```

this will not crash.

Also, there is a `magic_file` function, to which you pass the `cookie` and a file name and you can directly write this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <magic.h>

int main (void)
{
    magic_t cookie;

    cookie = magic_open(MAGIC_NONE);
    if (cookie != NULL)
    {
        /* you should load the database */
        if (magic_load(cookie, NULL) == 0)
        {
            const char *description;

            description = magic_file(cookie, "chaines");
            if (description != NULL)
                printf("%s\n", description);
            else
                printf("Unknown\n");
            magic_close(cookie);
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "error loading the magic database\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It shows me unknown that meas that there is problem with magic_descreption

Comment: It's never returning something in my case. May be the `mime` database has issues or something. I don't know how `libmagic` works internally.

Comment: may be you havnt add the right one ? me in both cases it shows me unknown but i can't find how to fix it.. and i have a remarq : magic_t is colored in black in my programme not in green ( or blue )

Comment: @user3568611 I just found out the problem, you should call `magic_load(magic_t, const char *const)` passing `NULL` to the second parameter it loads the default database. Check the updated answer.

Comment: yes and not,now I have magic_t in blue but it demand to initalise it so I putted magic_t cookie=0; When executing I have a segmentation error , I think the initialisation is wrong.

Comment: @user3568611 It has nothing to do with the color of the type name in the editor, just copy my second code and it will work.

Comment: Oh it works ! Thank you so much ! i want to put a +1 but I don't have the reputation for.. i will do it as soon i get some points.. Thank you again. So in futur programs if I use magic.h I sould absolutely us load_magic.

Comment: oh ! hope one day the same points as you !